# couldn't get the data from the openWeatherMap api JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

don't know where the problem is but nothing  was displayed in the div selected                                         .

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var lat, lng, data;

  // get the current location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lng = position.coords.longitude;
        });
    }else {
      alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
   }


//get the data from the openWeatherMap API
  function getData(){
    $.getJSON('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lng+'', function(json){
      data = json;
    });    
  }
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    getData();
    $(this).remove();
    $('.container').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#location').appendTo(data.name);
    $('#Weather-condition').appendTo(data.weather.main); 
    $('#wind-speed').appendTo(data.wind);
  });

});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any error?

Comment: NO ERRORS @yuriy636 .

Comment: Are you calling `getData()` from somewhere else than the code you posted? Post your HTML too, please.

Comment: about that yes i forget to call it, but when i did it nothing happen
http://codepen.io/sendja/pen/xOYbvr this is the app that I'm working on.

Comment: You know you have to use an API key in order to request data from openweathermap right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got a typo: getJESON instead of getJSON!

Comment: ah, just found another typo: lng with a capital g!

Comment: thank you for that but it seems that the problem is elsewhere @csabinho

Comment: it seems that the lat and lng variable are undefined 
but why is that ?

Comment: You could try to pass lat and lng as parameters to getData!

Answer (score 1):

you can find this problem from two side

- are you get data from ajax?  PS:you can add c.log(data)
- are you success show data in your web Page

Comment: well after the console 
the data variable is UNDEFINED in this case but why?

Comment: I think your url is wrong,check 'lat' and lnG field